# boost / creating streams

Tags: c++, boost, stream

Can you provide a simple example of the simplest code to create a boost "in" stream (boost::iostreams)? Im trying to create a stream that can be assigned to a file_sink later on. Thanx in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, the Boost.Iostreams documentation has examples all over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good place to start

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/